# Python: combining and rearranging arrays

Tags: python

I have two arrays:

```
array1=[[1,2],
        [3,4],
        [8,9]]

array2=[[11,12],
        [13,14],
        19,20]]
```

How can I combine the arrays to an array which looks like:

```
array=[([[1,11],
       [3,13],
       [8,19]]),
array([[[2,12],
       [4,14],
       [9,20]])]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.concatenate`, First output array can be created by concatenating first column of `array1` and `array2` along the axis =1, and similarly for second output array take second column from `array1` and `array2`.

Use:

```
new_arr1 = np.concatenate((array1[:, 0:1], array2[:, 0:1]), axis = 1)
new_arr2 = np.concatenate((array1[:, 1:2], array2[:, 1:2]), axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_arr1
array([[ 1, 11],
       [ 3, 13],
       [ 8, 19]])
>>> new_arr2
array([[ 2, 12],
       [ 4, 14],
       [ 9, 20]])
```

---

If you don't want to keep the original array we can do inplace changes which will only take extra memory for one column.

```
temp = array1[:, 1].copy()
array1[:, 1] = array2[:, 0]
array2[:, 0] = temp
```

Output:

```
>>> array1
array([[ 1, 11],
       [ 3, 13],
       [ 8, 19]])
>>> array2
array([[ 2, 12],
       [ 4, 14],
       [ 9, 20]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```py
import numpy as np
array_new1 = np.array([[a[0],b[0]] for a,b in zip(array1,array2)])
array_new2 = np.array([[a[1],b[1]] for a,b in zip(array1,array2)])
```

`zip` function will take many iterables (lists) and iterate each elements of all iterables (lists) parallely.

So, here I just iterated over 0 indexed element of both the arrays parallelly to get new array 1. It is done using list comprehension which is just another form of using `for loop`.
For new array 2, I iterated over 1 indexed elements of both arrays parallelly and combined them using list comprehension.

Comment: Good answer, but it would be great if you explained a little regarding list comprehensions and `zip`.

Comment: @AlexMetsai Thank you for the comment, I tried my best to explain the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, I have already upvoted your answer. :-)